# Read python shell

Tags: python, shell, stdin

Is there a way to check if there is anything entered in the shell without using raw_input?

For example instead of having something like `question = raw_input("Enter Q to quit")` I just want to read if anything is entered into the shell, "Q" and quit.

The reason I need this is because I don't want to block my program from executing with the `raw_input`. I need it to periodically check at any given point if "Q" is entered at all.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work

```
import sys
data_input = sys.stdin.readlines()
print "Counted", len(data_input), "lines."
```